Can I go back for clues later if I confront Risky Boots now?
Near the end of Shantae: Half Genie Hero, Uncle Mimic tells Shantae that she can either confront Risky Boots head on or search for four clues first to formulate a plan. I've been told that searching for the clues changes what ending I get.
If I decide to fight Risky Boots now, will I have an opportunity later to go back and find the clues for the alternate ending?

Yes. There is a save point right before the final boss. After beating the game, selecting "continue" will put you back at that save point. From there, you can use the Whistle to exit the stage and find the missing clues. When returning to Risky's Hideout, you can use the Warp Dance to avoid having to replay the stage.
